# Android Studio - Interface change

Tags: git, android, android-studio

I hope someone can help.

I have recently started to learn Android development, I'm mean literally just started and I'm not much past having downloaded studio.

Here's the problem - I'm following a tutorial and i was directed to clone and upload a git-hub file. This has changed the studio interface and I don't know where to start with it. All the file locations seem to have changed as well.

On starting the studio, crate new project follows a different path now, and I don't have the option to select a blank activity etc as i did before.

How can I change it back to the standard interface where you drag and drop text boxes and buttons etc?

I've tried uninstalling and re-installing and it makes no difference.

Thanks in advance everyone.

Aaron